# Question about Database architecture and Django models

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a project about cards.

I have two questions:

1) Question about database architecture:

I designed the database architecture, is it correct?[image]

2) Questions about models in Django:

a) I want 4 sections to be created when I create a new set (sections have different sizes).

b) When creating a new card, you could choose only those categories that belong to a certain set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Your "categories that belong to a certain set" sentence points to a relation between set and category and prevent to give your class a python's built-in token's name like "**set**"
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
2. Yes you can do it overriding django's save method

   e.g:

   ```
   class SetModel(models.Model):

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           section=Section()
           #do whatever you want with section in here
           section.save()
           super(SetModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
3. Yes you can write validator which checks whatever you want before saving model.
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/

Comment: What about the relationships between the Section model and other models?
How can I design it?

Comment: @YuriiDidyk well, the one who has the answer for that question is you :)